# How to resize an image keeping aspect ratio with cropperjs

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I'm trying to resize an image to a predefined size, keeping the aspect ratio of it. I've been using the following code to get the image data, but I don't know how to resize.

```js
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Comment: Did you tried anything ? seems written in the doc with [this](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/README.md#setaspectratioaspectratio) and [that](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/README.md#getimagedata)

Comment: None of these worked. `getImageData` returns information about the image, not the image. Also the `setAspectRatio` didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can potentially use

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas({ width: DESIRED_WIDTH, height: DESIRED_HEIGHT}).toDataURL(ORIGINAL_MIME_TYPE);
```

Its important to specify the original mime type of the image (png/gif etc) because otherwise you may end up with a significantly bigger image size in terms of file size.